# Problem with converting character string to date in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

Relatively new to Teradata. I have a table that appears to have been imported from Excel with everything as character. I'm trying to convert a character timestamp to either a timestamp or date--as long as I can calculate time intervals (days, months, years) I'm not really concerned with minimal error (1 day) isn't a big deal in this case.

They are currently formatted as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM with the, but for months Jan-Sept they are missing the leading 0. For example,

6/3/2020 5:19:11 PM

11/13/2020 11:37:12 AM

This is causing problems with functions like TO_DATE (when I extract the date part only) and TO_TIMESTAMP. I've googled and looked on stackoverflow, and while I've found answers I've been surprised that I haven't found any that help with my situation (this can't be that unique).

Here's what I've tried and what I get:

```
TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(ACTVTY_TIMESTAMP, 0, LENGTH(ACTVTY_TIMESTAMP) - 10))) AS newdate
```

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [9134 : HY000] YYYY value must be four digits and in the range 1-9999

```
TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(ACTVTY_TIMESTAMP, 0, LENGTH(ACTVTY_TIMESTAMP) - 10)), 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS newdate
```

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [9134 : HY000] Month of year must be two digits long

I've seen some similar situations where people suggested case when statements or regular expressions. I'm thinking there has to be a simple solution since this seems like it would be pretty common.

I'd really appreciate any guidance anyone can provide.

Many thanks,
Brian

Comment: In situations like this you can add a leading 0 to all dates and do a RIGHT('001', 2), so you would get 01.  Or if it was November you would use '011' but you would get just 11.

Comment: @Brad could you please elaborate or show me what you mean using the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to add leading 0s where needed.

```
select cast(regexp_replace('6/3/2020 5:19:11 PM', '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi:ssbT')
```

That will return 2020-06-03 17:19:11.